# Name conflicts between tags as classes and Tumblr theme's style classes

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I can apply styles to different posts based on their "#tags" using [`{TagsAsClasses}`](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts):

```
<div class="post {TagsAsClasses}">

div.tag {
    /* whatever styling */
}
```

This works fine, however if I already have a class in the theme with styling and then apply the tag with the same name as that class, the theme breaks. For example, the theme uses the class ".cover", and a post has the tag "#cover".

This would usually be fine because I would just change the class name, however I need to make sure that this same code works for about 65 students so I need to be able to define specific tags that the styling will affect.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure there are no conflicts between your theme's styling classes and any post's tag classes, you could add a prefix to all of your tag classes.

For example, instead of using `{TagsAsClasses}`, you have:

```
<div class="post {block:Tags}tag-{PlaintextTag} {/block:Tags}">
```

The ["Plaintext" prefix](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#variable-transformations) makes the theme variable `{Tag}` safe to include in HTML attributes.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but sorry; this doesn't answer my question. I only need to target specific tags (one or two) the rest are irrelevant, and I want to ensure there are no conflicts with theme classes.

However, as I said in my question, this needs to work across multiple themes as I want to make it as easy as possible for them to implement without having to add a prefix to all tags across all 65 students.

Comment: @John107 Does that mean every student gets their own theme? Are you only in control of just the CSS?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, but from all the searching i've done I don't think it can be done. Each student has their own unique css and html (which they can edit), I was looking for a quick and easy way to implement the above tumblr feature (with a few lines of code) without causing any errors to the students theme. Saving me from troubleshooting 65 different students themes.

Comment: It can be done quickly and easily. Just use a prefix like `tagstoclasses-{PlaintextTag}` which definitely won't coincidentally be in anyone's CSS.